# How to determine capacitance

Tags: capacitor

I’m looking to install a capacitor in a circuit which runs at 12V and <10A, and I want it to discharge in about 3 seconds.

The discharge voltage isn’t too important, but it’s probably best if it is as high as possible (not higher than 12V if that is even possible) for those 3 seconds.

The discharge time can be longer but probably should have an absolute minimum of 1.5 seconds.

Sorry if this sounds like gibberish. If I'm not giving enough info, please let me know what else i need to provide. I’m not an electrical guy; just working on a project and have no clue what I'm doing.

Comment: You can't just say "as high as possible" for the discharge voltage...that implies infinite capacitance and infinite cost. What is the real minimum voltage you can accept? Is the maximum current during the discharge equal to 10A?

Comment: the maximum current should be less than or equal to 10 amps, and i believe the minimum voltage needs to be about 5V

Comment: Since you say, "I ... have no clue what I'm doing", why don't you explain what you're doing so we can help you solve the problem rather than try to fix your solution? Your post is difficult to read. Please capitalise and punctuate properly.

Comment: I have a 12 volt circuit that is intermittent, not constant. I want to install a capacitor within it so that the capacitor discharges during the time that the circuit is essentially off, so that after the capacitor, it would likely be an unsteady voltage circuit, but there would still be some power instead of no power.  on the other end of the capacitor will be a relay, this relay needs to stay activated as long as the intermittant circuit is running (its on a switch). without a capacitor i think the relay would just be activated at the same intervals of the intermittent power in the circuit

Comment: so to make a comparison, the circuit I'm working with is kind of like the blinker on your car. power is only running to the lightbulb every 2 seconds or so (depends on make and model and such). I want to make it so that the blinker (assuming its led) would stay on for the entire time your switch (by your steering wheel) is on.

Comment: I meant that you should clarify this in your question and not in the comments. All the information required to answer your question should be in the one place so that the readers don't have to trawl through the comments to figure out what you're asking. It seems that your 10 A reference is irrelevant as your capacitor is required to hold only a relay and not the 10 A load.

Comment: This sounds like an example of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) -- you should try asking about your problem, first, rather than the solution you're trying to make. It's kind of difficult to understand exactly what you want from your question, here...

Answer (score 0):

If we assume that the discharge current is constant then $$I = C \frac{\Delta V}{\Delta t}$$ where \$I\$ is the discharge current, \$C\$ is the capacitance, \$\Delta V\$ is the change in voltage, and \$\Delta t\$ is the discharge time. Rearranging gives $$C = \frac{\Delta t \times I}{\Delta V}$$
For your case $$C = \frac{3 \times 10}{7} = 4.3\textrm{F}$$

Of course, this is an entirely theoretical analysis. You'll need to find capacitors that can support a discharge current of 10A, and the ESR must be low enough that it doesn't introduce a significant voltage drop in the capacitor itself.

Comment: If you read comment 4 on the question OP seems to be using a relay. I suspect the 10 A reference is not relevant to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Look up the holding current,Ih and rated current Ir to compute the ratio for your relay and the coil resistance Rc.

C=Ih*dt/dV where this slew rate dV/dt slows down due to the fixed RC time constant but has an exponential decay.

The slew rate dV/dt at the holding current of about 20% or TBD is now increased to about 4T=4RC or TBD

Then C=Ih/4RC so C^2=Ih/4R so plug in the holding current and coil R and advise us if Ih/Imax is much different from 20%.

## The problem

To charge up this supercap the surge current may burn out the switch contacts so a different design may be needed.