# how to determine value of a power storage capacitor in an intermittent circuit

Tags: capacitor, light

I made a post earlier about this but apparently there weren't enough details and i didn't explain it well enough so i will try this again:

I have a circuit which runs on intervals of 0.75 seconds on/off. (for example, if i had a lightswitch/lightbulb, i turn the lightswitch on, but the bulb goes on for 0.75s then turns off for 0.75s then turns on for 0.75s etc. etc. for the entire time that the lightswitch is turned on, when the lightswitch is off, the bulb is constantly off)

This circuit (when on) runs at 12V and when i had the multimeter set to the 10A setting, it showed 0.07, so I'm guessing thats 0.07A?

This circuit is being connected to the signal coil on a relay.

This relay coil says on it 12VDC, when checking with a multimeter on the 2k ohm setting it showed 270, guessing thats 270 ohms?.

I checked with an adjustable power source and the minimum voltage that activated the coil was 6V, although it could only jump from 4.5V to 6V so that was the smallest it would switch at.

What I am trying to do is install a capacitor before the relay, so that during that 0.75 seconds of off, the capacitor discharges at a minimum 6V.

so my current problem is that if i just install that relay directly into that intermittent wire, the relay switches on/off at the same time as that wire, I need it to stay on.

To make a comparison: this circuit is kind of like the signal lights on your car, they blink on/off/on/off with some unknown time interval. Say you had a light that is able to work at 6V but typically works at 12V. I am trying to install a capacitor, so that when you turn the switch on (by your steering wheel) that light would be constantly on for the entire duration that the switch is turned on. instead of blinking on/off/on/off.

Comment: let's see if I understand your question ... you have a 12V square wave signal, with a period of 1.5 seconds .... the signal has enough current to activate a relay .... the signal is present for a variable amount of time .... you would like to use the signal to activate a 6V relay that would stay activated during the low portions of the signal .... the relay would deactivate when the signal stopped for approximately 2 seconds(guessing here) .... you would like to use a capacitor to store a charge for use during the low portions of the signal ... you are asking what capacitance would be needed

Comment: you should really edit your first question, instead of posting again

Comment: Yes and no, the relay would deactivate when the signal stopped for greater than 0.75 seconds. After that 0.75 seconds of the signal being off, there would be another wave of 12V power which i think would resupply the capacitor with power. Once the switch turns off, and after greater than 0.75 seconds, then the relay should deactivate

Comment: So if i use the formula C = (T*I)/V, then i think T = 0.75, I = 0.07, and V = 6. This would give me a capacitance of 0.00875 Farad.... but i don't know if this is the right formula to use, or even if this idea would even work in the first place

Comment: You've already got answers on [your previous question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/381229/how-to-determine-capacitance). As *jsotola* said, you need to fix *that* question, not start a new one. We don't accept repeat questions here, to avoid duplicating effort. It would also help if you explain what your *real* goal is. You say that blinking car indicator / turn signals are *similar* to your signal source. When you're fixing your original question, please explain what your *actual* signal is. Are you trying to modify your car for LED turn signals, for example? Thanks.

Comment: You should probably not use a relay and use some other electronic switching element like a MOSFET. Why don't you post a complete schematic of what you are trying to do so we can answer this properly (as in what load are you trying to drive with the relay and how is it wired)? I think you can do what you want with a diode, a resistor, a capacitor and a MOSFET or transistor or two. If you insist on using the pulsing signal to drive the relay coil, you will require a ridiculously large capacitor.

Comment: this only adds to the confusion because it is totally unclear `After that 0.75 seconds of the signal being off, there would be another wave of 12V power which i think would resupply the capacitor with power`

Comment: -1 Fix your original question, this is an insult to the people who tried to help you the first time.

Comment: If you have additional information related to your original question, use the "edit" button to add the information there. Do not create a duplicate question.

Answer (score 0):

this is NOT an answer

get rid of most of your description and replace it with a timing chart similar to this one

**do it with your first question ... then delete this question**

[image]

you can use the **schematic editor**

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5ppsz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>